# Use jQuery append method to add element, but the class in element is invalid?

Tags: jquery, angular

I am using jQuery append method to add element in angular project, but the class in element is invalid, There is my code. The element can be added in document, but the style is invalid.

```js
constructor() {

    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
      jQuery('#add-device').on('click', function () {
        console.log('click');
        jQuery('#form-content').append('<div>\n' +
          '          <p class="custom-item1">01</p>\n' +
          '          <div class="custom-item2">\n' +
          '            <select>\n' +
          '              <option value="1">Option 1</option>\n' +
          '              <option value="2">Option 2</option>\n' +
          '              <option value="3">Option 3</option>\n' +
          '            </select>\n' +
          '          </div>\n' +
          '          <div class="custom-item3">\n' +
          '            <select>\n' +
          '              <option value="1">Option 1</option>\n' +
          '              <option value="2">Option 2</option>\n' +
          '              <option value="3">Option 3</option>\n' +
          '            </select>\n' +
          '          </div>\n' +
          '          <a class="custom-item4"><img src="../../../../assets/images/notice.png"></a>\n' +
          '        </div>');

      });

      jQuery('#form-content').on('click', '.delete', function () {
        console.log('delete');
        if (jQuery('#inputView').children().length !== 1 ) {
          jQuery(this).parent().remove();
        }

      });
    });
  }
```

```css
.custom-item1 {
  flex: 1;
}

.custom-item2 {
  flex: 3;
}

.custom-item3 {
  flex: 3;
}

.custom-item4 {
  flex: 1;
}

.form-custom-content > div {
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Anyone know why and how to solve this problem.Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by `but the class in element is invalid,`?

Comment: This is ugly, don't mess jQuery with Angular together. Which version of angular are you using?

Comment: The angular version is 5.0.1. Do you know how to add element with angular dynamically ?